# Swift - How to access Navigation Bar from another controller

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

So, my problem is, I have a collection view inside a table view, and I want to add a bar button item to the navigation bar inside the table view controller from the collection view controller. Can I actually do that?

*I've tried to pass the navigation controller from the table view controller to the collection view controller and then add the button from the collection view controller, but nothing happens.

Comment: Yes, it should be possible. Edit your question to include details of your flow and structure, along with the relevant code and what you’ve tried to debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a UINavigationController
whatever you push into this navigation you could access the navigation without passing it

self.navigationController

the NavigationBar is shared between all the controllers will be pushed into the navigation stack

the navigation item is only related to your controller

so if you added a navigation bar for A controller is a different navigation bar for the B controller even if both of them pushed to the same navigation controller

```html
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = .init(title: "Ate", style: .done)
```